# Failing Production Build of Ionic-3 app

Tags: cordova, webpack, ionic3, vendor

I am building an app using Ionic-3. I am using follwing command to build the app -

> ionic cordova build android --prod

When app starts it throws follwing error -

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at vendor.js:1
    at vendor.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:1)
```

> However when I build without “–prod” flag, app build just fine.

Here is my package.json file:
Package.json -

```
{
“name”: “ionic-hello-world”,
“author”: “Ionic Framework”,
“homepage”: “http://ionicframework.com/”,
“private”: true,
“scripts”: {
“clean”: “ionic-app-scripts clean”,
“build”: “ionic-app-scripts build”,
“ionic:build”: “ionic-app-scripts build”,
“ionic:serve”: “ionic-app-scripts serve”
},
“dependencies”: {
“@angular/common”: “5.2.9”,
“@angular/compiler”: “5.2.9”,
“@angular/compiler-cli”: “5.**strong text**2.9”,
“@angular/core”: “5.2.9”,
“@angular/forms”: “5.2.9”,
“@angular/http”: “5.2.9”,
“@angular/platform-browser”: “5.2.9”,
“@angular/platform-browser-dynamic”: “5.2.9”,
“@ionic-native/camera”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/core”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/device”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/firebase”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/in-app-browser”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/keyboard”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/push”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/social-sharing”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/splash-screen”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic-native/status-bar”: “4.7.0”,
“@ionic/storage”: “2.1.3”,
“@journeyapps/cordova-plugin-broadcaster”: “file:cordova-plugin-broadcaster”,
“Applozic-Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Chat-Plugin”: “file:Applozic-Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Chat-Plugin-master”,
“angularfire2”: “^5.0.0-rc.6.0”,
“com.applozic.phonegap”: “Applozic-Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Chat-Plugin-master”,
“com.razorpay.cordova”: “file:razorpay-cordova-master”,
“cordova-android”: “6.4.0”,
“cordova-ios”: “4.5.4”,
“cordova-plugin-broadcaster”: “cordova-plugin-broadcaster”,
“cordova-plugin-camera”: “^2.4.1”,
“cordova-plugin-compat”: “^1.2.0”,
“cordova-plugin-console”: “^1.1.0”,
“cordova-plugin-device”: “^1.1.7”,
“cordova-plugin-firebase”: “file:cordova-plugin-firebase”,
“cordova-plugin-inappbrowser”: “^1.7.2”,
“cordova-plugin-splashscreen”: “^4.1.0”,
“cordova-plugin-statusbar”: “^2.4.1”,
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”: “^1.3.3”,
“cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing”: “^5.3.2”,
“es6-promise-plugin”: “^4.2.2”,
“firebase”: “4.12.1”,
“ionic-angular”: “3.9.2”,
“ionic-img-viewer”: “^2.4.0”,
“ionic-plugin-keyboard”: “^2.2.1”,
“ionicons”: “3.0.0”,
“jquery”: “^3.2.1”,
“moment”: “^2.21.0”,
“ng2-translate”: “^5.0.0”,
“promise-polyfill”: “^6.1.0”,
“rxjs”: “5.5.2”,
“socket.io-client”: “^2.0.1”,
“sw-toolbox”: “3.6.0”,
“underscore”: “^1.8.3”,
“zone.js”: “0.8.18”
},
“devDependencies”: {
“@ionic/app-scripts”: “^3.1.8”,
“@types/jquery”: “^2.0.49”,
“@types/underscore”: “^1.8.8”,
“typescript”: “^2.7.2”
},
“cordovaPlugins”: [
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”
],
“cordovaPlatforms”: [],
“description”: “app2: An Ionic project”,
“cordova”: {
“plugins”: {
“cordova-plugin-console”: {},
“cordova-plugin-whitelist”: {},
“cordova-plugin-compat”: {},
“cordova-plugin-statusbar”: {},
“cordova-plugin-camera”: {},
“cordova-plugin-device”: {},
“cordova-plugin-inappbrowser”: {},
“ionic-plugin-keyboard”: {},
“cordova-plugin-splashscreen”: {},
“com.razorpay.cordova”: {},
“cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing”: {},
“cordova-plugin-broadcaster”: {},
“com.applozic.phonegap”: {},
“cordova-plugin-firebase”: {}
},
“platforms”: [
“android”,
“ios”
]
}
}
```

I tried some solution by downgrading the Typescript version -
~2.6.6 but not worked for me .

I feel that it may be related to app-script downloaded dependencies. And one of them not backward compatible. Not sure though.

Please help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by -

**ionic cordova build android --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs --release**

prod internally uses these but there seems to be a problem in aot(Ahead Of Time) complication / email pattern matching issue and it causes build failure.
:)